# Constraining numbers to a range based on a MASK and a COMPARE register

Tags: math, binary, embedded, bit-manipulation

Recently, I stumbled over the following problem in an embedded software project. I cannot yet figure out, under which conditions there is a unique solution and how it can be found.

Let us assume that we have a 16-bit MASK and a 16-bit COMPARE value and we want to set them, such that for a defined range of consecutive IDs {a, ..., b} (e.g. {0x78, 0x79, ..., 0x97}) those IDs satisfy bitwise

ID & MASK == COMPARE

while IDs outside that range do not satisfy the above equation.

As an example: If a=0x100 and b=0x1FF, the MASK is set as 0x700 and the COMPARE as 0x100.

I have the following questions:

1. What are the conditions for the minimal and maximal ID, so that uniquely defined MASK and COMPARE values exist?
2. How can they be calculated?

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: What you mean with **What are the conditions for the minimal and maximal ID**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `MASK` and `COMPARE` can be described as a string of `0` and `1` with wildcards (`*`) to indicate "don't care" positions. If there's a `*` left of a `0` or `1`, the string does not describe a continuous range. Thus, the strings that represent ranges are exactly those where all the `*` are at the right end. The combinations of `a` and `b` that can be checked this way are then those where we can divide the 16 bits into a left part and a right part such that `a` and `b` are equal in the left part and the right part is all zero for `a` and all ones for `b`. We can test this as follows:

```
((((a ^ b) + 1) | a) & b) == a
```